# Relative Spectrum respects Pullback

Tags: algebraic-geometry

$\require{AMScd}$
Let $(X,\mathcal O_X)$ be a scheme and $\mathcal A$ a quasi-coherent $\mathcal O_X$-algebra, i.e. a sheaf of ring $\mathcal A$ together with a morphism $\mathcal O_X \to \mathcal A$ making it a quasi-coherent $\mathcal O_X$-module.

Let consider the induced scheme $Spec(\mathcal A)$ the relative spectrum defined locally via $$\Gamma(U, \mathcal O_{Spec(\mathcal A)}):= \mathcal A(U)$$

gluing provides indeed a scheme.

Now let consider a morphism $g: Y \to X$ of schemes.
My question is why the construction above respects pullbacks; therefore why

$$Spec(g^*\mathcal A) \cong Spec(\mathcal A) \times_X Y$$

My ideas: I heard that $Spec(\mathcal A)$ represents the functor

$$\begin{eqnarray}  \label{constructions-equation-spec} F : \mathit{Sch}^{opp} &  \longrightarrow &  \textit{Sets} \\  T &  \longmapsto &  F(T) = \{ \text{pairs }(f, \varphi ) \text{ with } f:T \to X, \varphi: f^*\mathcal{A} \to \mathcal{O}_ T \text{ surjective }\}  \nonumber \end{eqnarray}$$

so using Yoneda lemma it suffice to show it on level of pairs as above. But how?

By the way: can it also be shown directly on the level of stalks using the definition of pullback functor of sheaves via $$f^{*}{\mathcal {G}}:=f^{-1}{\mathcal {G}}\otimes _{f^{-1}{\mathcal {O}}_{Y}}{\mathcal {O}}_{X}$$?

Is the induced map $Spec(\mathcal A) \to X$ set theoretically surjective?

Comment: Hint: check affine-locally and reduce your problem to the morphism of schemes associated to the structure map $A\to B$ which makes $B$ into an $A$-algebra.

Comment: @KReiser: Ok. If I consider the local case that $B$ is a $A$-algebra and $f: Spec(R) \to Spec(A)$ is the induced morphism by the ring map $A \to R$. 
My problem here is to "translate" $f^*B$ locally to the level of rings, especially how to cope with the functor $f^{-1} $ on the level of rings.

I guess your hint surgests to compare locally $B \otimes_A R$ with $f^*B \cong f^{-1}B \otimes_{f^{-1}A} R$. Now my problem is how translate $f^{-1}B$ (resp $f^{-1}A$) locally to rings?

Comment: Suppose $g:Y\to\operatorname{Spec} A$ is our morphism, and $\widetilde{B}$ is our sheaf of algebras. WLOG we may assume $Y=\operatorname{Spec} R$ because isomorphisms may be checked affine-locally. Then $g^*(\widetilde{B})=\widetilde{B\otimes_A R}$ as a sheaf on $Y$, so $\operatorname{Spec}(g^*\widetilde{B})=\operatorname{Spec} B\otimes_A R$ which is exactly the fiber product on the RHS. On the level of rings, $f^{-1}$ just changes the ring we consider the module over from $R$ to $A$ by letting $a\in A$ act by $f(a)\in R$ while not disturbing the module.

Comment: @KReiser:Let $\varphi: A \to R$ a rind morphism inducing the morphism $f: Spec(R) \to Spec(A)$ and the $A$-algebra $B$ becomes via $\widetilde{B}$ a $\mathcal{O}_A$-module.

For an open set $U \subset Spec(R)$ (wlog consider $U= D(r):= Spec(R) - V(r)$  for $r \in R$ ) 

the local sections of $f^{-1}\widetilde{B}$ on $U = D(r)$ are defined via

$$f^{-1}(\widetilde{B})(U):= \varinjlim_{f(U) \subset V} (\widetilde{B})(V) $$

I don't see from here how to see your argument that $f^{-1}$ on the level of ring just changes it. The problem is what is $f(U)= f(D(r)$.

Comment: We're over an affine space and therefore the only thing we need to do is consider global sections by the equivalence between modules over $\mathcal{O}_X(X)$ and modules over $\mathcal{O}_X$.